# Why doesn't the IMG scale maintaining aspect-ratio? CSS

Tags: css

So I am trying to put some PNG files/Logos side-by-side in one line. I used flexbox for this purpose. However, the aspect ratio of the files is not correct. When I increase the Width, the size increases, however, it takes up the full Height and the aspect ratio breaks down.

The HTML:
`

```
<section class="companyLogos">
        <img src="./images/logo-google.png" alt="Logo of Google">
        <img src="./images/logo-ibm.png" alt="Logo of IBM">
        <img src="./images/logo-microsoft.png" alt="Logo of Microsoft">
        <img src="./images/logo-hp.png" alt="Logo of HP">
        <img src="./images/logo-vector-graphics.png" alt="Logo of Vector Graphics">
    </section>
```

`

The CSS:
`

```
.companyLogos {
        width: 96%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .companyLogos img {
        width: 8%;
    }
```

`

[image: The output]

I am trying to do this:

[image: Target outcome]

Comment: Can you share a runnable snippet? Maybe `height: auto` does the job

Comment: It would be `height:100%` or `height:fit-content` but the images wouldn't be vertically align so you would have to add `align-items:center` to the container. I did this in an answer I deleted because `object-fit: contain` as [Roger Harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20825060/roger-harold) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74887596/17684809) do both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `object-fit: contain` like this:

```css
.companyLogos {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.companyLogos img {
  width: 8%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="companyLogos">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x280" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x260" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x240" alt="">
</section>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Following two approaches would be useful-

**1. Using `object-fit: contain`-**
If we use `object-fit: contain;` the image keeps its aspect ratio, but is resized to fit within the given dimension.

```css
.companyLogos {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.companyLogos img {
  width: 8%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="companyLogos">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of Google">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of IBM">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of Microsoft">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of HP">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of Vector Graphics">
</section>
```

**2. Using `object-fit: cover`-**
If we use `object-fit: cover;` the image keeps its aspect ratio and fills the given dimension. The image will be clipped to fit.

```css
.companyLogos {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.companyLogos img {
  width: 8%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="companyLogos">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of Google">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of IBM">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of Microsoft">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of HP">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/19/20/19/ball-2157465__340.png" alt="Logo of Vector Graphics">
</section>
```